# How can I package my qt application with Qt Creator in Nokia Qt SDK

Tags: qt, qt-creator, nokia, maemo, n900

I have written a simple qt application with qt creator, I have tested with PC simulation and N900 device, It's OK. Qt Creator created a .deb file in my mobile. but it can't be installed. The installer always complained "incompatible package...".

The SDK document says I can modify my application's version, or I can skip the package step in the project setting, but in my Qt creator, there is no these setting at all.
Can anyone help me, thanks! :)

Comment: Is the error "incomplete package" or "incompatible package"?

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake,It's "incompatible"...Thanks!

Comment: Package created by SDK can be installed in terminal: "dpkg- i packagename.deb" - but you propably already know that. And yeah, I would also like to know if there is a way to build package straight from SDK that works with Maemo installer.